# Duplicatas do mesmo autor orientam o usuário incorretamente

Tags: novo-recurso, razões-fechamento, perguntas-duplicadas

Toda pergunta marcada como duplicata exibe o seguinte aviso logo antes dos comentários:

> <sup>Esta pergunta foi feita antes e já tem uma resposta. Se essas respostas não abordarem completamente sua pergunta, [faça uma nova pergunta](/questions/ask).</sup>

<sup>(Esse texto poderia ser melhorado, mas isso fica para outro post)</sup>

Quando as duas perguntas são do mesmo autor, esse texto é **potencialmente impreciso** e, pior, **dá orientações incorretas**. Geralmente o autor duplica a pergunta porque não recebeu nenhuma resposta na original, ou pelo menos nenhuma resposta satisfatória. Se não houver resposta, é incorreto dizer que a pergunta já tem uma resposta. E é mais incorreto ainda orientar o usuário a postar uma nova pergunta, que é justamente o que não queremos que ele faça. Um exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25511/como-evitar-o-alarme-falso-de-um-antiv%C3%ADrus?lq=1

#### Sugestão de texto alternativo para esses casos

> <sup>Esta pergunta já foi feita antes. Por favor não poste a mesma pergunta mais de uma vez. Caso queira complementar sua pergunta, [edite a pergunta original](/#). Se quiser chamar mais atenção para sua pergunta, você ainda pode oferecer uma [recompensa](/help/bounty) nela.</sup>

Comment: Acredito que isso seja um problema em todos os sites da rede, mas decidi lançar o assunto aqui primeiro.

Comment: Tem meu apoio!!!

Comment: O meu também, mas então haveria duas formas de duplicata?

Comment: @JorgeB. O sistema é capaz de distinguir sozinho entre os dois tipos, então nada mudaria para quem vota pelo fechamento.

Answer (score 6):

Hoje eu acho que o fechamento do mesmo usuário deveria ter tratamento diferente. Em geral é abuso do sistema e quase nunca ajuda as buscas ficarem melhores. Provavelmente deveria remover depois de um tempo e advertir a pessoa por ter feito pergunta repetida.